# ip link set not assigning IP Address but ifup does

Tags: linux, networking, ifconfig, iproute2

Since ip is set to replace ifconfig, I'm trying to get myself used to using the ip suite of commands. I'm trying to enable my NIC with

```
 ip link set eth3 up
```

That doesn't assign an IPv4 address correctly. However, if I run

```
 ifup eth3
```

it works fine. I'm not sure what exactly the issue is or where to start with this.

Comment: do you mean if or ip ?

Comment: woops. thanks for pointing the typo out. i meant ip

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ifup is a command that reads the /etc/network/interfaces (or other files depending on distro) brings the link up and correctly configures the interfaces as specified.

Running `ip link` only changes or shows the link status.  It does not read the configuration file, it does not make any other changes.

As far as I can tell the only issue here is that you have an incorrect expectation of what should happen.

To put it differently. The `ip` command is the underlying command that does the raw configuration.  The `ifup` command can/does the ip command to perform the actual configuration.

Answer (score 9):

`ip link` just manages the physical link layer. It has nothing to do with addresses.

To manage your addresses, use `ip address`. For instance:

```
ip addr add 198.51.100.206/24 dev eth3
ip addr add 2001:db8:64ce:c633::2/64 dev eth3
```

And similarly for routes:

```
ip route add default via 198.51.100.1 dev eth3
ip route add default via 2001:db8:64c3:c633::1 dev eth3
```

You will find, on close inspection, that these are the commands your distribution's networking scripts are using.